# Instaloader gives KeyError: 'entry_data'

Tags: python, instagram, keyerror

```
l = instaloader.Instaloader()
post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(l.context, 'CHsQFeEKfFKs')
likers = []
i = 0
for like in post.get_likes():
    i += 1
    print(i)
    likers.append(like.username)
```

Every time I run this piece of code it gives me, KeyError: 'entry_data'
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by commenting out lines 150-153 from structure.py.
[Check this link for more information](https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/issues/824)

[image]